# Problemas con Scrapy Spider Web

Tags: python, scrapy

Quisiera que me apoyen en organizar mi data en columnas y filas.
Y otro problema es que el resultado del scraping no reconoce las tildes
Este es mi codigo:

```
import scrapy

    class ComputrabajoFechas(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'computrabajo'
    allowed_domains = ['computrabajo.com.pe']
    start_urls = ['https://www.computrabajo.com.pe/empleos-en-lima']

        def parse(self, response):
            for element in response.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[3]/ul'):
                item = { }
                item['Fecha'] = (response.xpath('//li[1]/span/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
                                 response.xpath('//li[2]/span/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
                                 response.xpath('//li[3]/span/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
                                 response.xpath('//li[4]/span/a/text()[1]').extract_first(),
                                 response.xpath('//li[5]/span/a/text()[1]').extract_first())
                yield item
```

Me resulta así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo que salga así en columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido! Se necesita más información para poderte ayudar, ¿Puedes poner el código que usas para guardar la información? Si hay algún código que organice dicha información antes, puedes agregarlo también por favor. Lo mejor es poner siempre todo el código relevante para solucionar tu problema, así se lo pones más fácil a las personas que desinteresadamente quieren ayudarte! Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así harás mejores preguntas y podrás ser ayudado en tus problemas!!

Answer (score 0):

Para el formato, al inicio de tu código debes agregar:

```
custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8' #Para no tener caracteres raros}
```

Lo otro me parece que con un \n entre los argumentos podrías solucionar el problema. Saludos.